# Difference between Neo4j Graph Algorithms and Graph Data Science

Tags: neo4j

I'm wondering what the difference is between the new Neo4j Graph Data Science library and the neo4j-contrib Graph Algorithms library.

Apparently they can't both be installed at the same time.  Does one replace the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the neo4j [Graph Data Science Library](https://neo4j.com/blog/announcing-neo4j-for-graph-data-science/?ref=social-blog) is replacing the Graph Algorithms Library.

You should now use the Graph Data Science Library, as it improves on the prior library and adds more features. Use the above link to learn more.